# Kernel Task taking up 300% CPU

Tags: macos

MacBook Air version 6,2 
System using 70% 
Is there a way to fix this? Been trying for hours

Comment: Hi - please edit and @ bmike me if you can’t solve this by cooling the computer externally.

Comment: @bmike Bottom side is completely cool while the fan is still on. Seems like a lot of people had this issue.